# run out on someone (meaning be used up)

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

The intransitive multi-word verb **run out** meaning *be used up* is well known.

The transitive multi-word verb **run out on** meaning {[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/run-out-on)}:

> run out on somebody
>
> (informal) to leave somebody that you live with, especially when they
>   need your help

(and probably used in analogous situations) is also well known.

However, I've recently come across the transitivised form used with the 'be used up' sense, and seem to remember hearing this many years ago:

**The [cold] water has never run out on me.**

Internet examples are usually the broadened usage {eg [a customer review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R27D78ZCC1NOWH)}:

*The battery has never run out on me.*

I can't find dictionary examples of this usage, and there aren't too many examples at all on the internet. Is this usage common enough to be considered acceptable?

Comment: Why would it not be acceptable?  To "run out on your girlfriend" is an idiomatic expression.  Using "run out" in other circumstances is just plain words.

Comment: Yes,  it's very common in AmE at least.

Comment: *run out on* is fairly common both in verbal as well as written (informal) content. I have seen usage even in newspaper articles.

Comment: @Hot Licks It's worrying that your comment has received two upvotes. Essentially you're saying 'If an expression exists, why bother investigating whether it can used with different meanings?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Quite the opposite.  Almost any idiom can also be interpreted as "just plain words" in an appropriate context.  (Though in this case it's an idiom within an idiom -- "run out on your xxxx" is one idiom, and "run out" is another idiom.  And, of course, "run" and "out" are words of their own as in "he ran out the door".)

Comment: 'Why would it not be acceptable?' I'm asking about the usage of 'on somebody' after the well-known 'be used up' meaning. You might as well say 'Why wouldn't "It is used up on me" be acceptable?'

Comment: @Mamta I can't find many examples, which is why I'm asking. Could you give some of the references (note I'm not asking about 'he ran out on his family' usages).

Comment: Here you go: https://reason.com/archives/2015/05/28/let-the-clock-run-out-on-the-nsa , http://gulfnews.com/opinion/editorials/the-clock-has-run-out-on-climate-change-1.1589057 and https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=166360

Comment: Thanks, Mamta. They're both the 'broadened usage' I mentioned, _clock_ for time interval allowed, and _battery_ for available energy in the battery. I think expressions like 'the coffee / biscuits ran out on us' are rare to extremely rare. Though @Hot Licks may have other data he's not yet revealed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You have never heard of a car running out of gas?  Would it not be fairly normal for someone to say "I was almost home and then the car ran out of gas on me"?  Or perhaps "I thought I was going to make it, but the gas ran out on me"?  No one's implying that the gas was disloyal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Note that it would be perfectly normal to say "The car broke down on me" or "The work piled up on me".  There's nothing sacred about "ran out" such that it can't precede "on me" like other verbal phrases.

Comment: There are 5 results in a Google search for ""ran out of petrol on me" as compared with tens of thousands for "ran out of gas on me". I'd not thought of using an Americanism. It seems that (1) this construction is much more common in the US; (2) the usual slot-fillers for 'the ____ ran out on me' are a small subset of logically applicable nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I suspect that in part the US/UK difference is due to the fact that the phrase "petrol on me" is a bit awkward to say/hear vs "gas on me".  A lot has to do with how a phrase "rolls off the tongue".

Comment: I'm asking about the second part, too. There seem very few examples in UK or US corpora for things like 'the flour / beer / wine / milk / sauce ran out on me'; 'gas' seems an or even the exception.  Considerably more (but not a large number) for more metaphorical usages like 'my pen ran out on me'. I wouldn't argue about the grammaticality of  'the staples ran out on me', but I'd be reluctant to use it. 'The stapler ...' would sound less awkward. I'm wondering _why_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is probably a U.S. or North American thing, where "on" binds to "me" more closely than it does to "run." In effect, "on me" means "during my use" or "during my administration" or (figuratively) "before I was ready."

Here's an example from LeezyKit of Pensacola, Florida, in a [review posted on TripAdvisor.com](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g304036-d318410-r145151328-Rupa_Wasi_Eco_Lodge-Aguas_Calientes_Sacred_Valley_Cusco_Region.html) on November 6, 2012:

> Also, the hot water **ran out on me** in the middle of my shower. It turned to freezing cold. We later found out that the hot water machine ran out of gas and that it would take 30 minutes for the hot water to start again. I had to finish my shower in the freezing cold and so did my husband.

Here, "the hot water ran out on me" means "the hot water dissipated to nothing ["ran out"] during my use of it ["on me"] (in the middle of my shower)."

And similarly from David Eddings, [*The Seeress of Kell*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SIcDJH9RICAC&pg=PA271&dq=%22supplies+ran+out+on+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMItYLd9pzGyAIVQepjCh0_jwQj#v=onepage&q=%22supplies%20ran%20out%20on%20me%22&f=false) (New York, 1991):

> "Got myself caught up in the mountains last winter," the old fellow replied. "Supplies **ran out on me**. Besides, I get hungry for talk now and then. The pony and the mule listen pretty good, but they don't answer very well, and the wolves up there move around so much that you can't hardly get a conversation started with them."

From a [translation of a letter](https://books.google.com/books?id=7HfWOvfomesC&pg=PA243&dq=%22money+ran+out+on+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI2pnH7J7GyAIVDMJjCh3kAQXh#v=onepage&q=%22money%20ran%20out%20on%20me%22&f=false) written by a Guatemalan woman on October 10, 1990, in Larry Siems, *Between the Lines: Letters Between Undocumented Mexican and Central American Immigrants and Their Families and Friends* (Tucson, Arizona, 1995):

> Mario we now have the car at home, we fixed up the entry and made a shed for it to go in during winter, and Tulio still isn't learning to drive because we don't have money for gas and even the grocery money **ran out on me** already, that's why he hasn't learned to drive, but one needs to have patience, ...

And from Alberta Richardson, [*In a Whale's Belly: This Poor Man Cried*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nW6pAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22check+ran+out+on+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIkYmPuqPGyAIVR9pjCh3GsQv4#v=onepage&q=%22check%20ran%20out%20on%20me%22&f=false) (Raleigh, North Carolina[?] 2013):

> "Wh—Where you work, Mac? Wh—What kind of work you do?" he asked McCall.
>
> “Ain't got no job right now man, and my unemployment check **ran out on me** last month. Talk about being flat broke, busted and disgusted, that's the story of my life[.]"

As for the related form "ran out of X on me," we have this representative example from [*McCall's* magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=nNgxAQAAIAAJ&q=%22ran+out+of+gas+on+me%22&dq=%22ran+out+of+gas+on+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMI_vqHy6TGyAIVUN5jCh2JeQK8), volume 102 (1974):

> I'm apprehensive about the continued smooth functioning of pistons and carburetor, and cars know it. Last July Minnie [the author's car] stealthily **ran out of gas on me** as I was on the way to play tennis. I had to walk to the nearest gas station, feeling more than faintly foolish in immaculate white shorts and white shirt.

This folksy idiomatic usage is quite familiar to me, and I believe it is fairly common in the United States. I suspect, though, that it is far more common in informal conversation than in writing that self-consciously strives for even a moderate level of formal correctness.

Comment: Thanks, Sven. Excellent answer; I naughtily hadn't even considered 'on me / him ...' being more closely bound than the string 'run out on'. The old _transitive multi-word verb_ ... _verb + prepositional phrase_ gradience. I'll look for a few more similar examples of this usage of 'on', but I suspect it's rarish to rare.